# How to zoom out after auto zoom in input text tag in Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, viewport

I have a little problem concerning the auto zoom in input text tag in Cordova.

Indeed, when the user touches the textarea of my page for example, the viewport is automatically zoomed. I agree with that, it allows a better visibility of what is written but when the user touches the button in order to leave the virtual keyboard the page is always zoomed and the user can't zoom out.
So whence my question : how to restaure the initial resolution after an auto zoom in input text tag in Cordova?

I hope you will understand what I mean.

Thanks for any help.

Have a good day !